# RichFaces: Submit inputText value from fileUpload

Tags: java, jsp, richfaces, form-submit

I've got this page:

```
    <rich:modalPanel id="modalEditPanelId" resizeable="false"
        autosized="false" moveable="false" keepVisualState="false"
        width="300" height="130" showWhenRendered="true"
        rendered="#{myBean.renderedEdit}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{lang.cga_edit_title}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="width: 60%">
            <h:outputText value="#{lang.cga_search_descr}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{myBean.datasetDescription}" />
            <rich:separator />
            <h:outputText value="#{lang.cga_edit_overwrite}" />
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.overwrite}" />
            <rich:separator />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid id="editButtons" columns="2">
            <a4j:commandButton id="modalEditBtnCancel"
                value="#{lang.msg_cancel}" reRender="modalEditPanelId, dataToShow">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false"
                    target="#{class.renderedEdit}" />
            </a4j:commandButton>
            <rich:fileUpload id="uploadNewDataset" allowFlash="true"
                fileUploadListener="#{myBean.editXls}" acceptedTypes="xlsx"
                addControlLabel="#{lang.msg_import_input}"
                maxFilesQuantity="1">
                <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete"
                    reRender="modalEditPanelId, dataToShow">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="false"
                        target="#{myBean.renderedEdit}" />
                </a4j:support>
            </rich:fileUpload>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </rich:modalPanel>
```

When I click on the fileUpload button, the fields datasetDescription and overwrite are obviously not submitted. 
I've also tried to set a valueChangeListener on the inputText, but this will never be called.
How can I save in my backing bean those values before or after I upload the file?